# Is it possible install Bugzilla into the apache server running collabnet subversion edge

Tags: apache, svn, bug-tracking, subversion-edge

I want to install bugzilla against the apache server that installed with collabnet edge.  I've already gotten everything installed, my problem is that I can't figure out which httpd.conf file i need to edit.  Collabnet Edge has about 5 conf files, all these files are autogenerated and warn "DO NOT EDIT" in the first line.

Does anyone know how I can do this?  if not is it possible to install another [instance]? of apache?

ps: Also this is on windows 2008 server, with IIS shut off.

pps: Also, I am open to the idea of moving my repo to another svn server/issue tracker. as long as it's free and runs on server2008.  I just have past experience with bugzilla (as a developer/enduser).

Any thoughts would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  It is.  **First, do not touch any files in the collabnet apache server install.**  I went ahead and installed a separate installed a separate instance of Apache, which I bound to an non-standard port.  I had to add an alias line to the new apache to create Bugzilla as a folder under my main site

```
NameVirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.local

<VirtualHost
 xxx.xxx.scgov.local>  
 ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx.local
 DocumentRoot "C:/Apache2.2/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost
 xxx.xxx.xxx.local>  
 ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx.local
 DocumentRoot "C:/bugzilla"
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "C:\bugzilla">
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
  Options +Indexes +ExecCGI
  DirectoryIndex index.cgi
  AllowOverride Limit FileInfo Indexes
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Once this was complete I was able to follow the tutorial at https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Win32Install

Also make sure you install ActivePerl @ C:\usr  if you don't you have to go in an change every *.cgi file....  read this tutorial on how to install ActivePerl to maximize portability with windows & linux  http://www.ricocheting.com/how-to-install-on-windows/perl

Comment: For records : The reason why you may not use the apache that comes with Edge is because it is customised to work only with Edge. There might be other libraries that you might require for other softwares which will be missing.